# Why Self.self print Self

Tags: swift

I have this code in a customized view:

```
class AView: UIView {
   
   func setup {
       Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("\(Self.self)", owner: self, options: nil)
   }
   
}
```

I expected this will load the nib file name with `AView`, it works no problem on debug mode. But when run under release mode, this crashes.

The error message is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: '_TtC10ATPlatformP33_BB740EC0B8824C2F1932C467ED63DEF214LanguageBundle </private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B0094397-EC2C-4550-8981-0CF2DCFB580C/xxx.app> (loaded)' with name 'Self''
```

That means `"\(Self.self)"`  returned `Self` string.

What I realized is when set `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` -> `Optimization Level` to `[-Onone]`, which works no crash.

Any one knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the bug [SR-14564](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-14564) "`"\(Self.self)"` causes issue on Xcode 12.5 when Swift is optimized", and it has already been fixed in Swift 5.5. You are probably using Xcode 12.5, which uses Swift 5.4. Try updating to the Xcode 13 Beta. You can download it [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/).

Comment: One more interesting thing is iPad device works fine, iPhone not. thanks.